# Seeking .htaccess help: Converting multiple subdomains (both HTTP and HTTPS) to www.domain.com using .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, subdomain, https

I've been trying to get an answer to this question on other forums (the folks at SuperUser thought this was the place I needed to post) and via my connections, but I haven't gotten very far. Hopefully you guys can help me find an answer.

I've got a dozen old subdomains that have been indexed by Google. These have been indexed as both HTTP AND HTTPS.

I've managed to redirect all the subdomains properly, provided they are not HTTPS, but can't get any of the HTTPS subdomains to property redirect.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain3.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great until someone goes to:

```
https://subdomain2.mysite.com$ 
which is not redirected back to http://www.mysite.com$
```

How can I get this to work? Additionally, I'm guessing there is an easier way to make it happen than setting up a dozen pairs of `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule`? Is there any way to do this in just a few lines, including one where I list all the subdomains?

I'd actually also like to redirect everything on `https://www.mysite.com$` to `http://www.mysite.com$` except for 3 folders.

These are `mysite.com/secure`, `mysite.com/store`, `mysite.com/user`. Is there any good way to add this to the *.htaccess* file?

Comment: I'm gust guessing here, but I think you need to match the HTTPS using the following condition. Adapted from http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on

Comment: @skibulk Adding that above any of the sets of rewrite conditions that I've already got doesn't do anything for me.  Any ideas?  Could there be some kind of conflict with another config file?

Comment: First of all, should this question belong to stackoverflow? Anyhow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108706/correctly-switching-between-http-and-https-using-htaccess might help you.

Answer (score 1):

About not repeating for each subdomain - shouldn't this work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```